# Can shiny display the finished output on webpage immediately, and do not wait for other unfinished outputs?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

In a shiny app, all of the outputs will never appear until the last render output is finished, but what I want is to show the finished output immediately.

For example, in this app the text output, table DT1, and table DT2 will show **simultaneously 10 sec after initialization**. But the more effective way is **to show text right away, table DT1 5 sec after, and finally table DT2.**

Is it possible?

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyBS)
library(DT)


genDF <- function() {
    Sys.sleep(5)
    return(iris)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
   mainPanel(
        h3('The renderPrint object will not appear until the last render object is completed'),
        bsButton("Btn", "Button"),
        verbatimTextOutput("Tx"),
        splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
          DTOutput("DT1"),
          DTOutput("DT2"))
      )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(TRUE, {
    output$Tx <- renderPrint({ input$Btn })
    TB1 <- genDF()
    output$DT1 <- renderDT(TB1)
    TB2 <- genDF()
    output$DT2 <- renderDT(TB2)
  }, once=TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried to move them into 3 different observeEvent blocks, but it didn't work.

```r
  observeEvent(TRUE, {
    output$Tx <- renderPrint({ input$Btn })
  }, once=TRUE)

  observeEvent(TRUE, {
    TB1 <- genDF()
    output$DT1 <- renderDT(TB1)
  }, once=TRUE)

  observeEvent(TRUE, {
    TB2 <- genDF()
    output$DT2 <- renderDT(TB2)
  }, once=TRUE)
```

I tried `future` and `promises` packages, but they don't work. The outputs still appear at the last second.

Comment: Why are these in an `observeEvent`? All the code changes for a given block will happen at once. If you want different times, try moving them to different blocks.

Comment: I tried to move them into 3 different `observeEvent` blocks, but they still appear at the last second.

Comment: There is no need for any `observeEvent` at all.  Just use `output$Tx <- renderPrint({ input$Btn })` and `output$DT1 <- renderDT(genDF())` and `output$DT2 <- renderDT(genDF())` inside your server function.  But, this does not appear to make them appear one at a time.  So it doesn't seem to solve your issue, but you should still drop the `observeEvent`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a simplified example of my more complicated situation, and I'm not sure if there is any difference on this issue between the `observeEvent`  function and just plain code inside the `server` function. So I prefer keep it.

Comment: if you want the table to show after button click `observeEvent` is required. regardless, removing it doesn't solve the issue. I am wondering if you can load your data which `genDF` function returns in the global environment, the only change this makes is that when the app loads the data is read once, if you have multiple versions of the table to show they won't need to load it again.

Comment: This doesn't solve this issue, but I did find that it can save time using future by using 
`plan(multisession)`,  and then running two return(iris) at the same using `genDF1 %<-% return(iris)` and `genDF2 %<-% return(iris)`.